# Java: Boolean not returning false to Main method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Here's a little code I wrote; in short, I'm plain stuck and can't figure out what Im doing wrong. Basically what my intention for the code is, is to check my boolean array; find out if true is listed more consecutive or if false is. False is of course listed more so it then should return false to my main method.

```
public class FalseBoolean
{
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      boolean[] guess = {false,true,false,false,false,true,true};
      boolean result = longerTF(guess);
   }

   public static boolean longerTF(boolean[] guess) {

       int variableTrue = 0;
       int variableFalse = 0;

       for(int x = 0; x < guess.length; x++) {
           if(guess[x] == true) {
               variableTrue++;
           } else {
               variableFalse++;
           }
           return variableFalse;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never use the value of `result` in main. How do you know this code doesn't work?

Comment: Is this code supposed to compile?  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what you want to achieve? false count?

Comment: You're trying to return an integer as a boolean. That shouldn't work. Also, you're always returning `variableFalse`, not the most consecutive value

Comment: `return variableFalse;` - your logic is wrong

Comment: @ScaryWombat Plus, it's within the loop

Comment: also `variableTrue` and `variableFalse` need to be reset.  You should also be looking at more than one value to test for `sequential`

Comment: whats your intention here return true/false depending upon the count of anyone of which is greater?and if so then you should consider comparing the count for each and return a boolean value as your function return bool value not int

Comment: You should look up the meaning of "consecutive", because it does not mean total count. There is a *total* of 4 false and 3 true values, but the max *consecutive* sequence of values are 3 false and 2 true. Your code is trying to find total counts, not consecutive counts.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This(Made some logic change)**

```
public class FalseBoolean
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    boolean[] guess = 
{false,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,true,true};

    boolean result = longerTF(guess);

    System.out.println(result);

}

public static boolean longerTF(boolean[] guess)
{

    int consecutiveVariableTrue = 0, maxConsecutiveVariableTrue = 0;
    int consecutiveVariableFalse = 0, maxConsecutiveVariableFalse = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < guess.length; x++)
    {
        if(guess[x] == true) {
            consecutiveVariableTrue++;
            if (maxConsecutiveVariableTrue < consecutiveVariableTrue)
                 maxConsecutiveVariableTrue = consecutiveVariableTrue;
        } else {
            consecutiveVariableTrue = 0;
        }

    }

    for(int x = 0; x < guess.length; x++)
    {
        if(guess[x] == false) {
            consecutiveVariableFalse++;
            if (maxConsecutiveVariableFalse < consecutiveVariableFalse)
                  maxConsecutiveVariableFalse = consecutiveVariableFalse;
        } else {
            consecutiveVariableFalse = 0;
        }

    }

    if (maxConsecutiveVariableTrue >= maxConsecutiveVariableFalse) {

        return true;

    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: How does this code do *find out if true is listed more consecutive*  All you are doing is counting the occurances

Comment: Ohhhh... I didn't read that...  I will update...

Comment: The if statement around the return statement is pointless. Just return the comparison

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem should be returning a boolean, not an integer. You can do this by simply checking which count  is greatest.

Your second problem is to return after you looked at the entire array, not just the first element.

```
public static boolean longerTF(boolean[] guess) {

   int variableTrue = 0;
   int variableFalse = 0;

   for(int x = 0; x < guess.length; x++) {
       if(guess[x]) {
           variableTrue++;
       } else {
           variableFalse++;
       }
   }
   return variableTrue >= variableFalse;
}
```

Note: you only need one counter for an array of two possible values ... For example,

```
int variableFalse = guess.length - variableTrue;
```

Your question asked for consecutive elements, but this code only returns which occurs the most in the entire array, so keep working on the logic

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return an `int` variable when you obviously declared your method as a `boolean` type. Do this instead:

```
if(variableFalse > variableTrue){
   return false;
}else if(variableTrue > variableFalse){
   return true;
}else{
   //Default return statement
}
```

Also, in this specific case (because you are processing an array), don't include the return statement in the `for` loop.

I would explain this better if I wasn't using mobile :P